# How to set up SSL proxy on Windows?

Tags: windows, proxy, ssl

How can I set up an SSL proxy on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever heard of "stunnel" ([stunnel docs & howtos](http://www.stunnel.org/?page=docs)) ?

I used it ages ago on Windows to set some in-house protocols to be "secured" (the other side being some low level http-based server).